# Facebook Comments - height is clipped

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I'm using the older FB  xfbml Comment module on my site (I'd upgrade were it not for problems with migration), with this code to embed it

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
    appId      : 'xxxxxxxxx',
    channelUrl : '//www.site_etc.com/channel.html',
    status     : true,
    cookie     : true,
    xfbml      : true
  });
  FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
}
(function(d){ var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;} js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true; js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"; ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref); }(document));
```

The problem I'm having is that whenever FB loads the Comments iframe, it is clipped in height. It consistently loads with a height of about 160px, no matter how many comments etc. there are, and I'm not able to get it to expand accordingly. I'm fairly certain there is no conflicting CSS, containers, etc.

I have no idea what is going on nor where to begin searching for this. Google had a few interesting hits but ultimately no solution -

http://bit.ly/11JzGh8